# On screen orientation change of my android app layout

Tags: android

When orientation of screen changes, I have read many a times that in order to save data of edit text and text view or any of the radio button I have to use `onSaveInstanceState()` method.

But when I'm changing the screen orientation my data of edit text, text view and radio button are not getting erased.

So what is the main purpose of using `onSaveInstanceState()` method. Why do we have to use it if my data are preserved safely ?

Answer (score 0):

Some Views/properties may be handled by default. You could go rooting through the docs to find out exactly which ones and how they are taken care of but...

I would recommend that you take manual control of these save/loads though to ensure that things are handled as you want them to be to avoid edge case bugs and also so you can then persist certain settings/properties/states if need be.

It really depends on the complexity and contents of your Activity/Fragment/Layout/View/Preference etc etc and if you even really need to remember the state things were a few moments ago.

---

- [`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

> This method is called before an activity may be killed so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state.
>
> Do not confuse this method with activity lifecycle callbacks such as onPause, which is always called when an activity is being placed in the background or on its way to destruction, or onStop which is called before destruction. One example of when onPause and onStop is called and not this method is when a user navigates back from activity B to activity A: there is no need to call onSaveInstanceState on B because that particular instance will never be restored, so the system avoids calling it. An example when onPause is called and not onSaveInstanceState is when activity B is launched in front of activity A: the system may avoid calling onSaveInstanceState on activity A if it isn't killed during the lifetime of B since the state of the user interface of A will stay intact.

- [`onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

> This method is called after onStart() when the activity is being re-initialized from a previously saved state.
>
> Most implementations will simply use onCreate(Bundle) to restore their state, but it is sometimes convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default implementation. The default implementation of this method performs a restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).

- On the default handling of your views with this pair of methods:

> The default implementation takes care of most of the UI per-instance state for you by calling View.onSaveInstanceState() on each view in the hierarchy that has an id, and by saving the id of the currently focused view (all of which is restored by the default implementation of onRestoreInstanceState). If you override this method to save additional information not captured by each individual view, you will likely want to call through to the default implementation, otherwise be prepared to save all of the state of each view yourself.

Comment: so it is recommended to use onsaveinstancestate() and also restore function? Even if by default my data are being preserved. Right?

Comment: As I said, it depends on your use case. If you need the state to be saved then do it yourself to ensure that it is. You can't always rely on the defaults as they may and likely do act differently across API versions. I'll edit some more info into my answer. Note the part about when `onSavedInstanceState(...)` would not get called though. this can be easily overlooked and hard to track down later.